Bond etf payment holding for short term
I've read that bond etfs pay a monthly dividend / coupon.
What happens if you hold the bond for less than a month, or between dividend payments?
What happens if you hold the bond just for the duration of the dividend payment?
I would have guessed that if the bond etf pays the dividend at a specific date, the etf price reflects that the day before or the day after, but I haven't seen much change.

See past questions about dividends. Prices adjust to absorb the pre/post dividend difference in value, precisely for the reasons you were hoping they wouldn't.

You don't hold a bond - you hold units of an ETF that owns many bonds. That ETF gets income from the coupon payments periodically from all of the bonds that it holds and from buying and selling bonds, in which case it gets the interest that accrues since the last coupon payment.
The value of the ETF reflects partly this constant flow of interest (both accrued and realized), plus the change in value of the actual bonds as interest rates change. Both of those change constantly, which is why you don't see spikes in value when the underlying bonds pay interest.  The interest income is accounted for gradually, not just when the bonds pay a coupon.
(This would be the same if you bought a single bond - you pay for whatever interest has accrued but not been paid when you buy the bond, and get it back either when you sell or get paid the full coupon.)
So the interest that the bonds pay is somewhat disconnected from the dividend that the ETF pays. When the ETF distributes a dividend (which is mostly funded from the bond coupons it receive), the value of the ETF drops by that amount since it's "cash out the door". Your wealth has not changed - you go from owning an ETF worth X to owning an ETF worth X-D and D in cash.

What happens if you hold the bond for less than a month, or between dividend payments?

You indirectly get the interest that accrues through the value of the bond ETF - but the value may also go down if market interest rates go up.

You must be a holder of the security on the 'ex-dividend' date to be paid a dividend. How long before or after said ex-dividend date may affect the income tax rate you are required to be paid on said dividend income money, but to be paid a dividend, it is only a matter of ownership of the security on the set date.
https://www.investor.gov/introduction-investing/investing-basics/glossary/ex-dividend-dates-when-are-you-entitled-stock-and
